# How do I correctly display fetched email content in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmail, nokogiri

Here is the code I am using to fetch emails and store them into my DB:

```
emails = imap.search([fp.filter_type, "#{fp.value}"])

emails.each do |message_id|

  msg = imap.fetch(message_id,'RFC822')[0].attr['RFC822']
  mail = Mail.read_from_string msg

  Email.create({
    :user_id    => self.id,
    :message_id => message_id.to_s,
    :email_from => mail.from[0], 
    :subject    => mail.subject, 
    :content    => mail.multipart? ? mail.html_part : mail.body.decoded,
    :sent_at    => mail.date
    }) if !Email.find_by_message_id(message_id.to_s)
end
```

When I render the content for an email record, it is not displayed correctly. However the email looks great on my GMail account. I need a way to store the correct HTML and display it just like it would seem in my email account. I also need to parse data out of these emails which is difficult as the DOM structure gets really messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
emails = imap.search([fp.filter_type, "#{fp.value}"])

emails.each do |message_id|

  msg = imap.fetch(message_id,'RFC822')[0].attr['RFC822']
  mail = Mail.read_from_string msg
  Email.create({
    :user_id            => self.id,
    :message_id         => message_id.to_s,
    :email_from         => mail.from[0], 
    :subject            => mail.subject, 
    :content            => mail.multipart? ? mail.html_part.body.to_s : mail.body.to_s,
    :merchant_id        => merchant.id,
    :filter_id          => filter.id,
    :filter_property_id => fp.id,
    :sent_at            => mail.date
    }) if !Email.find_by_message_id(message_id.to_s)
end

Email.all.collect {|e| e.run_parsers} if emails.size > 0 # ideally this should be initiated from email model
```

With this code I am able to get correct HTML and the view is exactly like in my GMail, well more or less.